# intel xdk jquery css not working

Tags: android, jquery, css, intel-xdk

i have aproblem to use .css in  jquery to make effect on images .. effect worked on Emulator 
but not work in real android device

and i ca

```js
$('.grayscale').click(function(){
                   $('img').css({'-webkit-filter':'grayscale(1)','filter':'grayscale(1)'});
                });
```

n not use overflow-x:scroll , -webkit-overflow-x:scroll

thanks .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this StackOverflow reply, which should answer your question: [Css filter blur is not working in Cordova app, Android 4.4.2, Nexus 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229019/css-filter-blur-is-not-working-in-cordova-app-android-4-4-2-nexus-4)

In essence, you are inside a webview when you run on a real device, which means you are not inside the latest and greatest browser. The webview is like an "embedded browser" that is built into the firmware, so it does not get updated like apps do. See this blog for some more background: http://blogs.intel.com/evangelists/2014/09/02/html5-web-app-webview-app

There is a special linting extension for the Brackets editor that is built into the XDK that can help you identify unsupported CSS issues. Go to the "File --> Extension Manager..." menu item and install the "XLint for Intel XDK" extension.

Also, if you check the caniuse.com support for the "Android browser" this will give you some idea as to what is supported by the webview, but it is not fully accurate, since the webview typically has a lesser feature set than the stock Android browser.

Comment: how can i use "XLint for Intel XDK" extension?

if it worked automaticly or what ?

Comment: Install the extension and open the file of interest within the editor (Brackets) inside the XDK. Look at the very bottom and you'll see a small green check mark, meaning no issues found, or a small orange triangle, meaning issues found. Click the orange triangle and you'll get a list of the issues. You can do the same with the various jslint/hint, csshint, etc. tools.